# How to access an HTML ref in VueJS 3 and Typescript with Vue Class Component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-class-components

I'm banging my head on the following problem: I created a QRCode component using Vue 3 and Typescript with the following code:

```
<template>
  <canvas ref="qrcodeVue"> </canvas>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import QRCode from "qrcode";
import { Vue, Options } from "vue-class-component";
import { ref } from "vue";

@Options({
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    size: {
      type: [Number, String],
      validator: (s: [number | string]) => isNaN(Number(s)) !== true
    },
    level: {
      type: String,
      validator: (l: string) => ["L", "Q", "M", "H"].indexOf(l) > -1
    },
    background: String,
    foreground: String
  }
})
export default class QRCodeVue extends Vue {
  value = "";
  size: number | string = 100;
  level: "L" | "Q" | "M" | "H" = "L";
  background = "#ffffff";
  foreground = "#0000ff";

  mounted() {
    const _size = Number(this.size);
    const scale = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    const qrcodeVue = ref<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);

    QRCode.toCanvas(qrcodeVue, this.value, {
      scale: scale,
      width: _size,
      color: { dark: this.foreground, light: this.background },
      errorCorrectionLevel: this.level
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

But `qrcodeVue` is always referring to nothing, I never get access to the canvas itself.  What am I missing? Where should I put this `ref()` code? I also tried with `defineComponent` with the same result. Thanks for any clue.

(BTW, I also tried to use the npm `qrcode-vue` package but it doesn't seem to support Vue 3)

Comment: I think you might be missing the `.value` part of qrcodeVue to access the canvas element `QRCode.toCanvas(qrcodeVue.value, this.value, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim. See Dan's answer below for the real thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare the ref `qrcodeVue` as a class property first, and not inside `mounted`.

Only then will it be be available and populated with the ref element in `mounted`:

```js
export default class QRCodeVue extends Vue {
  qrcodeVue = ref<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null); // not inside mounted

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.qrcodeVue);  // now it's available
  }
}
```

This is the equivalent to the following Vue 3 `setup` syntax:

```js
setup() {
  const qrcodeVue = ref(null);
  onMounted(() => {
    console.log(qrcodeVue.value);
  })
  return {
    qrcodeVue
  }
}
```